# how to remove visual studio PIN TAB icon (on tabs, obviously)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, productivity-power-tools

is there a way to REMOVE COMPLETELY the pin tab option in visual studio 2010 (how?), i keep clicking it by accident :( **i want it GONE.** i never use it and always click it by accident.

[image: pin that i need removed]

thnx

p.s. right clicking on the PIN icon does bring up some customize dialog, but was unable to remove it - couldn't recognize the option.

[image: config dialog that appears on right clicking the PIN icon]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Scroll to the bottom of the `Document Tab Well -> General` page, click `Advanced options...`, then uncheck `Show pin button in unpinned tabs`

Comment: thnx, can accept in 9 minutes :P anyhow - i DID NOT SEE the advanced button. must be blind lol. if you can see the screenshot, i have SHOW ALL SETTINGS checked, so probably i was not expecting it to be hidden.

Answer (score 45):

To remove the pin tab icon from Visual Studio 2019, Visual Studio 2017, Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2012, there is an option within the Visual Studio Environment settings.

Tools Menu -> Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows -> Under the "Pinned Tabs" section, uncheck "Show pin button in unpinned tabs"

[image: An image showing where to find Visual Studio 2019, 2017, 2015, 2013, 2012 Pinned Tabs setting]

The image above is from Visual studio 2019, but is relevant to Visual Studio 2017, 2015, 2013, and 2012 as well.

Comment: I was irritated with the pin thing, same as OP, and found this helpful.  Also confirmed this works in Visual Studio 2022, just did it.

Answer (score 2):

I've been investigating this in VS2012, since the option appears to have been removed from the UI.

I think I may have just found it in the registry though, under:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\DialogPage\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.Options.TabsAndWindowsOptionPage

There's an option 'ShowPinButtonInUnpinnedTabs' which is set to 'True' on my machine.

I've just tried setting this option to 'False' and it works: removing the 'pin' button and freeing up the space for the filename.  Just what I was after.

Comment: I've just discovered for myself what @jtlowe comments below - the option appears to have been moved, and is now under Environment-Tabs and Windows.  I popped back here to report my finding to discover that I was beaten to it by 25 minutes (coincidence).